# Process finished with exit code 139 (interrupted by signal 11: SIGSEGV) - How can I solve this issue with my code below?

Tags: python, algorithm, memory, routes, exit-code

What could be causing this issue?

```
Process finished with exit code 139 (interrupted by signal 11: SIGSEGV)
```

Here is my script:

```
import googlemaps
import webbrowser
from ortools.constraint_solver import routing_enums_pb2
from ortools.constraint_solver import pywrapcp
import mysql.connector
from dfs import depth_first_search
from genetic import create_population, calculate_fitness, genetic_algorithm
from timeWindowing import get_user_time_windows, group_packages_by_time_window
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from gis import solve_gis_vrp, plot_optimal_route  # Import the GIS-based functions from gis.py

# Replace 'YOUR_API_KEY' with your Google Maps API Key
gmaps = googlemaps.Client(
    key='my-api-key')

# Specify your starting point
starting_point = "Al Aqiq, Riyadh 13519, Saudi Arabia"

# Global variables for addresses and coordinates_mapping
addresses = {}
coordinates_mapping = {}

def get_coordinates_from_database():
    try:
        connection = mysql.connector.connect(
            host='localhost',
            user='root',
            password='my-password',
            database='database-name',
            port= port-number
        )
        cursor = connection.cursor()

        # Fetch full information from the database
        query_fetch_addresses = "SELECT id, building_number, postal_code, city, street_name, latitude, longitude, District, short_address FROM spl_api_data"
        cursor.execute(query_fetch_addresses)
        result = cursor.fetchall()

        if not result:
            print("No addresses found in the database.")
            return None

        global addresses
        addresses = {row[8]: row for row in result}  # Using short_address as a key
        return addresses

    except mysql.connector.Error as err:
        print("MySQL Error: {}".format(err))
        return None

    finally:
        if connection.is_connected():
            cursor.close()
            connection.close()

def open_google_maps_url(starting_point, coordinates):
    google_maps_url = f"https://www.google.com/maps/dir/{starting_point}/" + "/".join(
        [f"{lat},{lng}" for lat, lng in coordinates])
    webbrowser.open(google_maps_url)

def calculate_distance(lat1, lon1, lat2, lon2):
    from math import radians, sin, cos, sqrt, atan2
    lat1, lon1, lat2, lon2 = map(radians, [lat1, lon1, lat2, lon2])
    dlat = lat2 - lat1
    dlon = lon2 - lon1
    a = sin(dlat / 2) ** 2 + cos(lat1) * cos(lat2) * sin(dlon / 2) ** 2
    c = 2 * atan2(sqrt(a), sqrt(1 - a))
    return 6371 * c  # Radius of Earth in kilometers

def solve_vrp_with_traffic(starting_point, destination_coordinates, user_time_windows):
    manager = pywrapcp.RoutingIndexManager(len(destination_coordinates), 1, 0)
    routing = pywrapcp.RoutingModel(manager)

    coordinates = [(float(row[5]), float(row[6])) for row in destination_coordinates]
    distance_matrix = [[0] * len(coordinates) for _ in range(len(coordinates))]

    for i in range(len(coordinates)):
        for j in range(len(coordinates)):
            if i != j:
                lat1, lon1 = coordinates[i]
                lat2, lon2 = coordinates[j]
                distance_matrix[i][j] = calculate_distance(lat1, lon1, lat2, lon2)

    def distance_callback(from_index, to_index):
        from_node = manager.IndexToNode(from_index)
        to_node = manager.IndexToNode(to_index)

        directions_result = gmaps.directions(
            f"{coordinates[from_node][0]}, {coordinates[from_node][1]}",
            f"{coordinates[to_node][0]}, {coordinates[to_node][1]}",
            mode="driving",
            departure_time="now",
            traffic_model="best_guess",
        )

        return directions_result[0]["legs"][0]["duration_in_traffic"]["value"]

    transit_callback_index = routing.RegisterTransitCallback(distance_callback)
    routing.SetArcCostEvaluatorOfAllVehicles(transit_callback_index)

    search_parameters = pywrapcp.DefaultRoutingSearchParameters()
    search_parameters.first_solution_strategy = (
        routing_enums_pb2.FirstSolutionStrategy.PATH_CHEAPEST_ARC
    )

    solution = routing.SolveWithParameters(search_parameters)

    if solution:
        index = routing.Start(0)
        route = []
        while not routing.IsEnd(index):
            node_index = manager.IndexToNode(int(index))
            route.append(node_index)
            index = int(solution.Value(routing.NextVar(index)))

        current_location = starting_point
        optimized_route = [destination_coordinates[index][8] for index in route]

        open_google_maps_url(starting_point, coordinates)
        return optimized_route
    else:
        print("VRP solution not found.")
        return None

def solve_combined(starting_point, destination_coordinates, user_time_windows):
    global coordinates_mapping

    coordinates_mapping = {addr[8]: (float(addr[5]), float(addr[6])) for addr in destination_coordinates}

    grouped_packages = group_packages_by_time_window(user_time_windows, addresses)
    optimized_routes = []

    for group in grouped_packages:
        if len(group) > 1:
            print(f"Delivering Group: {', '.join([addr[0] for addr in group])} together")
            routes = solve_vrp_with_traffic(starting_point, [addresses.get(addr[0]) for addr in group], user_time_windows)
            optimized_routes.append(routes)
        else:
            print(f"Delivering Single: {group[0][0]}")
            routes = solve_vrp_with_traffic(starting_point, [addresses.get(group[0][0])], user_time_windows)
            optimized_routes.append(routes)

    # Apply genetic algorithm to further optimize routes
    for i in range(len(optimized_routes)):
        if optimized_routes[i]:
            # Create population for genetic algorithm
            population = create_population(num_individuals=5, num_genes=len(optimized_routes[i]))

            # Create distance matrix for genetic algorithm
            distance_matrix = [[0] * len(optimized_routes[i]) for _ in range(len(optimized_routes[i]))]
            for j in range(len(optimized_routes[i])):
                for k in range(len(optimized_routes[i])):
                    if j != k:
                        distance_matrix[j][k] = calculate_distance(
                            coordinates_mapping[optimized_routes[i][j]][0],
                            coordinates_mapping[optimized_routes[i][j]][1],
                            coordinates_mapping[optimized_routes[i][k]][0],
                            coordinates_mapping[optimized_routes[i][k]][1]
                        )

            # Run genetic algorithm
            optimized_genetic_route = genetic_algorithm(population, distance_matrix, num_generations=50)

            # Update the route with the optimized genetic route
            optimized_routes[i] = [optimized_routes[i][idx] for idx in optimized_genetic_route.genes]

    return optimized_routes

def main():
    global addresses

    addresses = get_coordinates_from_database()

    if not addresses:
        return

    print("Available Short Addresses:")
    for short_address in addresses:
        print(short_address)

    num_packages = int(input("How many packages will be delivered? "))

    if num_packages <= 0:
        print("Invalid number of packages.")
        return

    chosen_short_addresses = []
    for i in range(1, num_packages + 1):
        chosen_short_address = input(f"Enter the short address {i}: ")
        chosen_short_addresses.append(chosen_short_address)

    user_time_windows = get_user_time_windows(chosen_short_addresses, addresses)

    destination_coordinates = [addresses.get(short_address) for short_address in chosen_short_addresses]

    if None in destination_coordinates:
        print("Invalid short address.")
        return

    grouped_packages = group_packages_by_time_window(user_time_windows, addresses)

    # Call the GIS-based optimization function
    optimal_route = solve_gis_vrp(list(coordinates_mapping.values()))

    print("Chosen Route (GIS Algorithm):")
    if optimal_route:
        plot_optimal_route(list(coordinates_mapping.values()), optimal_route)
    else:
        print("No valid route found within the specified time windows.")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

I am trying to know what is causing this issue. The issue comes right after I run the code and add my inputs. I checked for the error and tried gdb but nothing for me is helpful.

Please help me find the issue - I read that some libraries might be causing the issue? what could those libraries be?